# simpleWebRTC signalmaster - setting a signaling + STUN and TURN

Tags: php, webrtc, signaling, signalmaster

I used `simpleWebRTC` as a kind of multi video app.

Now I need to set up a signaling server.
The problem: I have no node knowledge.

Possible solutions:

1. is there a solution in `PHP`? (yea... probably not....)
2. is there some service?
   ( I did try `Xirsys` - did not connect successfully to there `Stun` and Turn + they do not specify a signaling server.
   looked up `Twilio` and `PubNub` -  did not find documentation on simply connecting to signaling, Stun, Turn - without building everything through their system)
3. Is there some simple recipe for setting up signalmaster on node - for someone with no real understanding in node?

Comment: Do you want to host this on your own server, or use a hosting provider?

Comment: Thank you @xdumaine. I would prefer a hosting provider. Though if you can recommend on a way / tutorial to host my own server for a node.js newbie ... then i'm also interested :-)

Answer (score 1):

XirSys have a bunch of demo's at https://github.com/xirdev/xsdk.  This provides both a standalone signalling demo and a demo of SimpleWebRTC connected to both XirSys TURN servers and XirSys signalling.

I hope this helps?

Comment: Thank you @LeeSylvester. I have tried them - the issue is that though there STUN/TURN works well - I was unable to use their signaling server through simpleWebRTC signalmaster (and still using simpleWebRTC sandbox signaling server)